# Awk delete line that contains data

Tags: awk

I want to delete a line if it contains a value that is specified.

```
2 5 8
1 3 7
8 5 9
```

So if I wanted to delete a line containing 7 as the third field:

```
{
if($3 == 7){
####delete the line
}
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It should be enough to say

```
$ awk '$3 != 7'
```

Note that this a numerical comparison, and will omit lines in which the third field is, for example, "0.7e1", but it will work for the sample data you provide.

Answer (score 9):

**delete a line containing 7**

```
awk '!/7/' yourFile
```

Comment: Escaping `!` is not the solution.  The solution is to not use `tcsh`!

Answer (score 7):

The other answers work. Here's why

Awk's standard processing model is to read a line of input, optionally match that line, and if matched (optionally) print the input. The other solutions use a negation match, so lines are printed **unless** the match is made.

Your code sample doesn't use a negation match: it says "if something is true, do it". Because you want to delete the input, when you match that target, you can just skip printing it.

```
{
  if($3 == 7){
     #skip printing this line
     next
  }
}
```

IHTH.

Comment: This does not work unless you add an `else` statement which says `print` in it.

Comment: The question was "So if I wanted to delete a line containing 7 as the third field:". I think I've answered that question.Thanks for your concern! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
awk '$3  /7/ {next} {print}'
```